# CakePdf set Tcpdf engine options

Tags: php, cakephp

i want to to implement cakepdf in my project and i want to use tcpdf as pdf engine. i know the recommendet engine was WkHtmlToPdf but i prefer the tcpdf engine. and i want to know how i can implement engine specific options for tcpdf.

i tried it over the the options array in the Configuration but nothing works. i also tried it over the `viewBuilder->setOptions` function but again nothing works. as example i need to disable the header and footer and i know it works with the `setPrintHeader => false`.

i tried it in the `AppController` with this

```php
Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.Tcpdf',
    'orientation' => 'portrait',
    'download' => true,
    'options' => [
        'setPrintHeader' => false,
        'setPrintFooter' => false
    ]
]);
```

and also with this

```php
$this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CakePdf.Pdf');
$this->viewBuilder()->setOptions([
    'pdfConfig' => [
        'orientation' => 'portrait',
        'filename' => 'test_',
        'setPrintHeader' => false,
        'setPrintFooter' => false
    ]
]);
```

nothing of these works. the header and footer lines also print on the pdf. how i can disable this ?